# Change column data type from bigint to date in sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, types

I am trying to change the column data type from bigint to date type directly its showing error:

> "Unable to modify table.   Explicit conversion from data type bigint
>   to date is not allowed."

even I tried to change using alter query again got this error

> "Operand type clash: bigint is incompatible with date".

Please help..

What I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE emp_det1 ALTER COLUMN dob date
```

Comment: Change how? Do you mean CAST or ALTER TABLE? Show us what you do.

Comment: @jarlh alter table here is my query: 
ALTER TABLE emp_det1
ALTER COLUMN dob date;

Comment: Add a new date column. Do UPDATE to copy and convert the existing bigint dates to the new column. When done, drop the old column. Perhaps rename the new column. (Check for dependencies before you do this! foreign keys, indexes, triggers, views etc.)

Comment: You can't convert bigint to date. you must go through varchar first. Also, how is this even remotely related to c#?

Comment: Can you post some of your example dates, in the bigint format?

Answer (score 0):

It errors because your bigint column has data in it that cannot be explicitly converted to a datetime.  Below code tests the theory, and will fail.  Try it again without the data insert, it will work.  The post comment that suggests creating a new datetime column and transferring the data whilst converting is your best option...assuming your bigint values can indeed be converted to a datetime at all.

```
create table #test (MyCol bigint)

insert into #test (MyCol) values(3123456789)

alter table #test 
alter column MyCol datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates you cannot convert bigint to date.

You would need to do some logic to convert it:

For example 10 April 2016 would be stored as 4102016 where as 10 December 2016 would be 12102016.  There is a character difference.

My recommendation would be:

- Backup the data, either my copying the table or taking a backup.
- Create a temporary table containing the pk and the dob.
- Add a varchar column to the temp table and populate it with the dobs. (chardate)
- Set all the dobs to null in the original table.
- Change the data type on the column to date.
- Run an update on the original table from the temporary table with the correct logic to convert the date.

That logic would vary depending on your dateformat but for the US (mm/dd/yyyy) would look something like this:

```
update emp_det1 
set dob = case 
             when len(chardate) = 8 
                then convert(date,left(chardate,2)+'/'+substring(chardate,3,2)+'/'+right(chardate,4),101)  
             when len(chardate) = 7 
                then convert(date,'0'+left(chardate,1)+'/'+substring(chardate,2,2)+'/'+right(chardate,4),101)  
from emp_det1 
    join #conv as conv 
       on emp_det1.pk = conv.pk
```

You can change the converts to try_converts to find ineligible dates, I would also recommend running some select statements prior to the update to make sure the data looks right before committing.